# Limit $v_{n+1}=\sqrt{{v_n}^2+5^{-n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\lbrace v_n\rbrace^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a sequence defined by $v_1=1$ and $v_{n+1}=\sqrt{{v_n}^2+5^{-n}}$ for $n\geq1$. Then what will be $lim_{n\to\infty}v_n$ ?

First of all, I don't know whether the sequence is convergent OR divergent. If we assume the convergence of the sequence, then we take $L=lim_{n\to\infty}v_n$ and we get $L=\sqrt{L^2+5^{-n}}$, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you take limits on both sides then you end up with $L=|L|$ (not what you suggest), not allowing you to find $L$.

Taking $w_n=v_n^2$ we have $w_1=1$ and $w_{n+1}=w_n+5^{-n}$.

So $w_2=1+\frac15$, $w_3=1+\frac15+\frac1{5^2}$, $w_4=1+\frac15+\frac1{5^2}+\frac1{5^3},\cdots$ et cetera.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$v_{n+1}=\sqrt{{v_n}^2+5^{-n}} \Rightarrow v_{n+1}^2={v_n}^2+5^{-n} \stackrel{v_n^2=a_n}\Rightarrow a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{5^n}.$$

$$a_2=a_1+\frac{1}{5};$$
$$a_3=a_2+\frac{1}{5^2}=(a_1+\frac{1}{5})+\frac{1}{5^2}.$$
$$a_4=a_3+\frac{1}{5^3}=(a_1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5^2})+\frac{1}{5^3}.$$
$$...$$
$$a_{n+1}=a_1+\frac{\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\left(\frac15\right)^n\right)}{1-\frac15}=a_1+\frac14-\frac14\left(\frac15\right)^n.$$
$$v_{n+1}^2=v_1^2+\frac14-\frac14\left(\frac15\right)^n=1+\frac14-\frac14\left(\frac15\right)^n.$$
$$v_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+\frac14-\frac14\left(\frac15\right)^n}.$$
Finally:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}v_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$